# mean of two arrays in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have:

```
x = [1,2,3]

y = [2,3,4]
```

I want to find the average so the result is:

```
z = [1.5,2.5,3.5]
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592), and we also [don't answer homework questions](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166). Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Answer (score 3):

Use `map` to iterate and return the mean value

```
var output = x.map((s,i)=> (s+y[i])/2);
```

**Demo**

```js
var x = [1, 2, 3];
var y = [2, 3, 4];
var output = x.map((s, i) => (s + y[i]) / 2);
console.log(output);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.

Answer (score 0):

You could take an arbitrary count of arrays and sum only the part for the result.

```js
var x = [1, 2, 3],
    y = [2, 3, 4],
    result = [x, y].reduce((r, a, i, o) => a.map((b, j) => (r[j] || 0) + b / o.length), []);
    
console.log(result);
```